# Merge multiple dicts with same key-value pair to one dict python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of dicts stored in the list. I want to merge the same dicts in to one. i have three fields. Task_id provides which field to be checked. value is the value of that field. First it checks the value in the dict and it creates a new dict for the dicts to be merged. if all the values are same and one of the value is only different, then it merges the dict to one. How to make it possible

Here's the sample code i tried:

```
field_to_be_check ="state"
merger = ["city", "ads"]
merge_name = ["cities", "my_ads"]

data = [
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad1', 'city': 'tirunelveli'}, 
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad4', 'city': 'nagerkoil'}, 
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad1', 'city': 'tuticorin'}, 
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad1', 'city': 'madurai'}, 
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad1', 'city': 'chennai'}, 
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'palakad'}, 
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'guruvayor'}, 
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'kolikodu'}, 
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'kottayam'}, 
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'idukki'}, 
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Akola'}, 
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Washim'}, 
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Jalna'}, 
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Nanded'}, 
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Latur'}
]

d = []
list1 = []
for item in data:
    value = item[field_to_be_check]
    inserted = False
    for l in list1: 
        if l[field_to_be_check] == value:
            inserted = True
            for m_name in merge_name:

    if inserted == False:
        list1.append(item)

print(list1)
```

Required Output:

```
   [
    {'state': 'tamil nadu','my_ads':[{'ads': 'ad1'},{'ads': 'ad4'}], 'cities':[{'city': 'tirunelveli'},{'city': 'nagerkoil'},{'city': 'tuticorin'},{'city': 'madurai'},{'city': 'chennai'}]}, 
    {'state': 'kerala',,'my_ads':[{'ads': 'ad2'}], 'cities': [{'city': 'palakad'},{'city': 'guruvayor'},{'city': 'kolikodu'},{'city': 'kottayam'},{'city': 'idukki'}]}, 
    {'state': 'mumbai', 'my_ads':[{'ads': 'ad3'}],'cities':[{'city': 'Akola'},{'city': 'Washim'},{'city': 'Jalna'},{'city': 'Nanded'},{'city': 'Latur'}]}
    ]
```

Comment: You don't want a `'cities'` *and* a `'city'` key, depending on how many cities there are. You always want a `'cities'` key, which sometimes only has one city in it.

Comment: why discriminate the city kerla, it is not following the pattern you said in the output ?

Comment: in the value field, i have given conditions. show that, it should check on that two states only. if it's there, it should merge the cities and combine it to one and assign to target cities

Comment: changed my required output....

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the values for `haps` and `ads` are always the same for every `state`? What if they are not?

Comment: You can actually use `itertools.groupby` for it, which simplies your code a lot @SmackAlpha! Check my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect scenario to see the power of [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
Note that I have assumed haps, state and ads will be present in all dictionaries, and will be similar in repetitions

```
from itertools import groupby

field_to_be_check =  "state"
merger = ["city", "ads"]
merge_name = ["cities", "my_ads"]

data = [
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad1', 'city': 'tirunelveli'},
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad4', 'city': 'nagerkoil'},
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad1', 'city': 'tuticorin'},
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad1', 'city': 'madurai'},
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad1', 'city': 'chennai'},
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'palakad'},
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'guruvayor'},
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'kolikodu'},
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'kottayam'},
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'idukki'},
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Akola'},
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Washim'},
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Jalna'},
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Nanded'},
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Latur'}
]

#Function to make the merger lists
def process_group(group, merger_item):

    item_set = set()
    item_list = []
    for item in group:
        item_set.add(item[merger_item])

    for item in item_set:
        item_list.append({merger_item: item})

    return item_list

#Group on haps, state and ads
grp = groupby(data,key=lambda x:(x[field_to_be_check]))
result = []

#Iterate through the group and build your result list
for model, group in grp:
    cities_dict = {}

    cities_dict[field_to_be_check] = model

    group_list = list(group)

    #Make the list for merger fields
    for idx, name in enumerate(merger):
        cities_dict[merge_name[idx]] = process_group(group_list, name)

    result.append(cities_dict)

print(result)
```

The output will look like

```
[{'state': 'tamil nadu', 
'cities': [{'city': 'nagerkoil'}, {'city': 'tuticorin'}, {'city': 'chennai'}, {'city': 'madurai'}, {'city': 'tirunelveli'}], 
'my_ads': [{'ads': 'ad4'}, {'ads': 'ad1'}]}, 
{'state': 'kerala', 
'cities': [{'city': 'guruvayor'}, {'city': 'idukki'}, {'city': 'kottayam'}, {'city': 'palakad'}, {'city': 'kolikodu'}], 
'my_ads': [{'ads': 'ad2'}]}, 
{'state': 'mumbai', 
'cities': [{'city': 'Jalna'}, {'city': 'Nanded'}, {'city': 'Washim'}, {'city': 'Latur'}, {'city': 'Akola'}], 
'my_ads': [{'ads': 'ad3'}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked.  but i have modified the question for merging multiple dicts and added 3 different fileds at the start. is it possible to get the required  output regarding the question.

Comment: thank u. but i want to merge according to the above three fields. In the "field_to_be_check ="state"", i will set the value to be grouped.  In the merger,I will set the what are fields to be merged and in the "merge_name = ["cities", "my_ads"]", i assign the merged values to the dict. these 3 are handled by user. the user can give any fields in the "merger" he wish to merge .how to make it possible there.

Comment: Actually you are grouping both on `haps` and `state`, and  merging `city` and `ads` in the latest example, do you agree?

Comment: i am grouping with state. and then i am merging city and ads according to the user wish.

Comment: No you are actually grouping both on `haps` and `state`, just that the value of haps and state end up being the same for all dictionaries, check again!

Comment: Okay, so if that is established! it is fine if my update my code according to this?

Comment: Can you confirm the values of `field_to_be_check`, `merger` and `merger_name` again for me please

Comment: updated the question code and required output. please see the output. i don't need haps in the output. this is the confirmed one. see the question, the above three fields needed. in there, the user specify the fields

Comment: Updated the example to use the variables! Please check the code and the output @SmackAlpha

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help! Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you @SmackAlpha :)

Answer (score 1):

```
field_to_be_check ="state"
merger = ["city", "ads"]
merge_name = ["cities", "my_ads"]

data = [
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad1', 'city': 'tirunelveli'}, 
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad4', 'city': 'nagerkoil'}, 
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad1', 'city': 'tuticorin'}, 
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad1', 'city': 'madurai'}, 
{'haps': 'hap0', 'state': 'tamil nadu', 'ads': 'ad1', 'city': 'chennai'}, 
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'palakad'}, 
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'guruvayor'}, 
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'kolikodu'}, 
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'kottayam'}, 
{'haps': 'hap1', 'state': 'kerala', 'ads': 'ad2', 'city': 'idukki'}, 
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Akola'}, 
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Washim'}, 
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Jalna'}, 
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Nanded'}, 
{'haps': 'hap2', 'state': 'mumbai', 'ads': 'ad3', 'city': 'Latur'}
]
# merger and merge_name must be one to one.
the_dict = {m:mn for m, mn in zip(merger, merge_name)}
# {"city":"cities", "ads":"my_ads"}  merge_name
newdata = data.copy()
# create new_ret as result
new_ret = [{field_to_be_check:i, **{i:[] for i in merge_name}} for i in set([i[field_to_be_check] for i in data])]
# print(new_ret, "this is new_ret")
for val in new_ret:
    for k in newdata:
        if val[field_to_be_check] != k[field_to_be_check]:
            continue
        tmp = {i:k[i] for i in merger}
        for single in tmp:
            if {single:tmp[single]} not in val[the_dict[single]]:
                val[the_dict[single]].append({single:tmp[single]})
print(new_ret)
```

Comment: this code maybe not good, i think it can solve your problem. Try it ?

Comment: This code doesn't work for me, Could you please explain it more!

Comment: Thanks. it worked.  but i have modified the question for merging multiple dicts and added 3 different fileds at the start. is it possible to get the required  output regarding the question.

Comment: I updated the question code, maybe not good and easy to read. you can try it @Smack Alpha